# ReactJS fetch not returning error and returning incorrect data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, qliksense

Im trying to run a fetch to check if the user can access a url. If the user session is activated the url will return a object or the url will return 401. Below is my code.
My fetch is not returning errors or the correct data. When I access the url via chrome, the data returned is correct.

```
 var reuurl = "https://nrtj9zddtsba1vo.eu.qlikcloud.com/api/v1/audits";
    fetch(reuurl, { // line 24 in console.log
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Qlik-Web-Integration-ID": webIntegrationId, //this is an id
       
      },
      mode: "no-cors",
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response); //line 33 in console.log
        if (response.status === 401) {
          console.log("hey");
          // do what you need to do here
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

The console.log returns
when authenticated the current wrong result is  (image1)
[image: When authenticated the current wrong result is]

When authenticated the object should return the following (image 2)
[image: The expected result when authenticated should be]
When not authenticated the current result is which is not correct, it should return an error
[image: When not authenticated the current result is which is not correct]

Answer (score 1):

it was a cors issue. after i whitelisted my domain, it works

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) ,

> The simplest use of fetch() takes one argument — the path to the resource you want to fetch — and does not directly return the JSON response body but instead returns a promise that resolves with a Response object.

```
 fetch(reuurl, { // line 24 in console.log
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Qlik-Web-Integration-ID": webIntegrationId, //this is an id
       
      },
      mode: "no-cors",
    })
      .then(function (response) {
         return response.json();
      })
       .then(function (result) {
           console.log(result) // this will be your actual result
        }) 
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: I now get the error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (line 40)

`fetch(reuurl, { // line 24 in console.log
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Qlik-Web-Integration-ID": webIntegrationId, //this is an id
       
      },
      mode: "no-cors",
    })
      .then(function (response) {
         return response.json();
      })
       .then(function (result) {
           console.log(result) // this will be your actual result
        }) 
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error); // line 40
      });`

Comment: That's strange , the syntax looks fine to me .

Comment: it was a cors issue. after i whitelisted my domain, it works